# ReDim Preserve 3 Dimensinal array VBA

Tags: vba, catia

I am working on VB code in catia.There are multiple sheets and each sheet has few tables for which the rows and columns and number of tables are not fixed. I want to create a 3 dimensional array  which can capture each table data into each 2 Dimensional array under it. I tried Redim and Redim preserve but its not working.

here is the code example.

table 1

1  2  3  4  5

2  3  2  3  2

1  2  1  1  4

table 2

9  8  8

7  8  6

these are sample of tables in each sheet.. Say i was able to calculate dimensions of the table and number of table in sheet.

here is the sample of code i tried.

```
Dim array() as variant

Dim ntables as integer 'Number of tables

Dim rcount as integer  

Dim ccount as integer

for each table in tables

rcount=table.rows.count

ccount=table.columns.count

redim preserve array(ntables,rcount,ccount) as varient

next
```

''' '''

i want a multi dimensional array as

array(0)

```
  array(0,0)

        array(0,0,1)

        array(0,0,2)

        array(0,0,3)

        array(0,0,4)

        array(0,0,5)

  array(0,1)

        array(0,1,1)

        array(0,1,2)

        array(0,1,3)

        array(0,1,4)

        array(0,1,5)

 array(0,2)

        array(0,2,1)

        array(0,2,2)

        array(0,2,3)

        array(0,2,4)

        array(0,2,5)
```

array(1)

```
  array(1,0)

        array(1,0,1)

        array(1,0,2)

        array(1,0,3)

  array(1,1)

        array(1,1,1)

        array(1,1,2)

        array(1,1,3)
```

Comment: `ReDim` can only resize the first dimension; consider using another type of data structure.

Comment: Also `varient` is probably undefined ;-)

Comment: Look into `Collection` for use as an array where you can add/remove items.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - last dimension not first?

Comment: @TimWilliams [indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement)! ...and it's the `Preserve` modifier not `ReDim` itself: "Modifier used to preserve the data in the existing array *when you change the size of **only the last dimension***."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a 3D array  consider to use a `Collection` of 2D arrays, if only the number of tables varies.

Consider the following working example (using 2 tables)

```
Public Sub TestFillData()

    Dim tables() As Variant
    tables = Array( _
        Range("A2").Resize(16, 4), _
        Range("I2").Resize(100, 7) _
        )
        
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In tables
        col.Add item.Value2    ' Range().Value2 returns a 2D array
                               ' when more than one cell is referenced.
    Next
    
    ' col.Count() = 2
    ' col(1) = 16x4 array
    ' col(2) = 100x7 array


End Sub
```